# how to decouple cache item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, model-view-controller

I am facing an issue while performing the basic operation .

Technology : c#, Asp.net mvc

I am fetching a cache item and adding it to an viewbag to display it on view,

```
CacheItem temp= cache.GetCacheItem(key + "names");
ViewBag.name1=temp.Value;
VieBag.name2= temp.Value;
List<string> nameList= new List<string>();
nameList= (List<string>)temp.value;
```

Later if I change any one value ,like *nameList[0]=null*, is resulting in change for all the remaining ones

How can I decouple them?

Comment: You would need to make a copy of the object temp.value.      
Try nameList = new List<string>((List<string>)temp.value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*List* is a referent type which means *list* does not store the value, it only points to a value, in this case name of list points to some list in memory. Using operator `=` you are not copying the value, but the reference on that variable. Here is an example for non referent type:

`int a = 10;
int b = a;
b = 20`

This way value of `b` will be *20* and value of `a` will be *10* because `int` is a value type.

However, with lists it is not the case.

`nameList= (List<string>)temp.value;`

This means variable `nameList` will point to the exact same list that is pointed by `temp.value` and any change to one of the lists will reflect to the other.

You need to copy all elements from one list to another. In this case:

`foreach (var item in (List<string>)temp.value)
{
    nameList.Add(String.Copy(item);
}`

Notice the `String.Copy` method. `string` is also a referent type, therefore you need to create a copy of it. `list2.Add(item);` will only add existing item (string) to the list `nameList`, therefore two lists will contain the same object in memory.

Same is for user objects, or any other objects. If you want to add those objects to new list, make a copy of object. So not only the list is a referent type, but also the object. It can go in depth because an object can contain another object as its field or property and you also need to create a copy of that.

On the other hand, if you had for example a list of elements of type `int` you won't need to create a copy of each element, because `int` is not a referent type, it is a value type. However, you will still need to create a new list, because list is a referent type.